# Why the editorwindow is not in the center of the screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class Search : Editor
{
    [MenuItem("Assets/Search", false, 1000)]
    private static void Search()
    {
        EditorWindow ew = new EditorWindow();
        int width = 322;
        int height = 278;
        int x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        int y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        ew.position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);

        ew.Show();
    }
}
```

The editorwindow show in the position 0,0 top left corner.

This is working :

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class Search : Editor
{
[MenuItem("Assets/Search", false, 1000)]
private static void Search()
{
EditorWindow ew = new EditorWindow();
int width = 322;
int height = 278;
int x = (Screen.currentResolution.width) / 2;
int y = (Screen.currentResolution.height) / 2;

```
    ew.Show();
    ew.position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
}
```

}

Comment: Well dump out the values and see what it says

Comment: Ok I found the problem. I had to show it first then set the position.